# scrolling content inside of paper-dialog

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

We are trying to derive a reusable modal dialog from `paper-dialog`.

We need to find a way to create a scrolling area inside the dialog.
`paper-dialog-scrollable` does not fit our needs as we don't know how deep the scrolling area is nested and we do not want our client to need to write javascript code. We'd like to work with plain css. This is our minimal example:

```
        <paper-dialog id="minidlgexample">
          <div id="dlgbody">
            <div id="header" style="background-color: green;">
              <div>I'm the header</div>
            </div>
              <!-- This overflow:auto has no effect :( -->
              <div id="contentcontainer"  style="overflow:auto;">
                <div id="content" style="background-color: #16738F; height: 2345px;">Yay. 2300px of contents</div>
              </div>
            <div id="footer" style="background-color: yellow;">
              <div>Footer</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </paper-dialog>
```

The dialog itself is sized correctly, but the `div` with id `contentcontainer` does not display scrollbars but is displayed at its full height - until far below the bottom of the screen the footer is displayed.